# yfinance 1 minute bars have 0 volume for its newest bar

Tags: python, dataframe, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I created an indicator in python that downloads historical data from yahoo using yfinance. Everything was working perfectly and then suddenly the newest row that gets downloaded for the tickers I use has 0 volume. This volume completely messes up the indicators I'm calculating, especially the swap. I know I can delete that row but then id is behind a minute with the indicators.  Is this common? What could be the reason for the newest row to show 0 as volume?

I've tried changing periods and intervals and the same thing happens with 5 min, 30 min,1 hour, but the 1 day everything works perfectly.

Comment: Sometimes the yahoo finance has some issues with updating the historical data of the stocks. Check out other websites to see if the stocks really has 0 volume at your particular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

I believe yahoo finance gives value data only for daily or higher interval.